# Having trouble getting this loop to run properly

Tags: python, loops

I am a first year programming student and I am having trouble trying to get my code to loop properly and I would like some pointers on how I can get it to run as desired. I am running a program that will calculate change with a preset stock of 10 of each coin, price and payment will be input by the user and change will be returned by the number of coins left in the stock. Right now i am having difficulties trying to get the program to return the 'insufficient funds' and the 'no change' print statements and trying to get it to loop over from quarters to dimes to nickels and pennies properly, I am not sure what I could be doing wrong.

```
quarters = 10
dimes = 10
nickels = 10
pennies = 10
stock = quarters, dimes, nickels, pennies
print("\nWelcome to change-making program.")

print("\nStock: {} quarters, {} dimes, {} nickels, and {} pennies".format(
            quarters, dimes, nickels, pennies))
in_str = float(input("Enter the purchase price (xx.xx) or 'q' to quit: "))
payment_int = int(input("Input dollars paid (int):"))
change_sum = float(payment_int) - in_str
#in_str = float(input("Enter the purchase price (xx.xx) or 'q' to quit: "))
while change_sum >= 0:

            if payment_int < in_str:
                print("Insufficient funds")
                break
            elif payment_int == in_str:
                print("No Change")
                break
            else:
                if quarters > 0 and change_sum >= 0.25:

                    change_sum = change_sum - 0.25
                    quarters -= 1

                    print(quarters, change_sum)



                elif dimes > 0 and 0.25 > change_sum >= 0.10:

                    change_sum = change_sum - 0.1
                    dimes -= 1
                    print(dimes, change_sum)
                elif nickels > 0 and 0.1 > change_sum >= 0.05:
                    change_sum = change_sum - 0.05
                    nickels -= 1
                    print(nickels, change_sum)
                elif pennies > 0 and 0.05 > change_sum >= 0.01:
                    change_sum = change_sum -0.01
                    pennies -=1
                    print(pennies, change_sum)
                else:
                    if change_sum == 0.0:

                        break


print("\nStock: {} quarters, {} dimes, {} nickels, and {} pennies".format(
            quarters, dimes, nickels, pennies))
print(change_sum)
```

Comment: `if payment_int < in_str:` should go before the `while` loop since in that case, `change_sum` will be < 0 and the `while` never gets entered.

Comment: Also, you should consider using `int` instead of `float`. Floating point rounding errors can cause issues. Convert the money values to pennies and work with that. See: [Is floating point math broken?](//stackoverflow.com/q/588004)

Answer (score 0):

If the fund is insufficient, then `change_sum` is `<0` and the `while` loop never runs. That's why you don't get "insufficient fund" message. You should first check the sufficiency and then start the loop:

Just change this part:

```
while change_sum >= 0:
    if payment_int < in_str:
        print("Insufficient funds")
        break
    elif payment_int == in_str:
        print("No Change")
        break
    else:
        if quarters > 0 and change_sum >= 0.25:
```

to this:

```
if payment_int < in_str:
    print("Insufficient funds")
    break
elif payment_int == in_str:
    print("No Change")
    break

while change_sum >= 0:
    if quarters > 0 and change_sum >= 0.25:
```

Comment: You should explain what exact change you made and what issue it fixes and why. "_Copy/Paste this code_" is not a good answer for StackOverflow.

Comment: This helps with the print statements, however, I am still having trouble trying to get the if and elif statements in my code to loop properly. By this i mean if the user inputs 2 as the purchase price and 5 as the dollars paid amount, my program will halt at 50 cents remaining as I have ran out of quarters and will not loop to dimes as desired.

Comment: @kj2k18 Think about (in your example of 2 and 5) when change is down to $.50 and you are out of quarters. It will check `elif dimes > 0 and 25 > change_sum >= 10:` but 25 is less than `change_sum`. You just need `elif dimes > 0 and change_sum >= 10:`.